# jQuery Hide Div of associated PHP MySQL results in While Loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Having an issue.  I need to remove the associated element on the click of a button from a list of results provided by a MySQL query.  Only the first image is being hidden on the click of the remove button.  The rest of the images returned do nothing.

Here is my code :

PHP:

```
<?php 
while ($image_row = mysqli_fetch_array($image_result)) { ?>
<span class="listing_image_preview" id="image_<?php echo $image_row['id']; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $image_row['image_thumb']; ?>" style="border:6px solid #EEE; margin:6px;" />
<button id="remove_image" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" imageId="<?php echo $image_row['id']; ?>">Remove</button>
</span>
<?php
}
?>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#remove_image").click(function() {

        var image_id = $(this).attr('imageId');

        $('#image_'+image_id).hide();
    })
});
```

Comment: can't repeat ID's in a page...change buttons to class in element and selector...will work fine

Comment: Could you post an example? I guess I am confused.  I thought the IDs were unique based on the image IDs.  Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: element id's ... `<button id="remove_image">` ... they are like an address ... must be unique in each page. With duplication when you are clicking the other ones...nothing happens because there are no event listeners attached to them

Comment: Got it, works great.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

All your buttons have the same id:

```
<button id="remove_image"
```

And your jquery script will only find one element with the following selector:

```
$("#remove_image")
```

Here's one way to solve it:

1. Add `remove_on_click` to the button's class (I also made the id's unique)

```
    <?php 
    while ($image_row = mysqli_fetch_array($image_result)) { ?>
    <span class="listing_image_preview" id="image_<?php echo $image_row['id']; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $image_row['image_thumb']; ?>" style="border:6px solid #EEE; margin:6px;" />
    <button id="remove_image_<?php echo $image_row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-xs remove_on_click" imageId="<?php echo $image_row['id']; ?>">Remove</button>
    </span>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

2. In your jquery script select on class `remove_on_click`:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".remove_on_click").click(function() {

            var image_id = $(this).attr('imageId');

            $('#image_'+image_id).hide();
        })
    });
```